# FAT32 External HDD formated with Mac OS not mountable on a Windows machine

Tags: macos, mac, external-hard-drive, mount, formatting

I have an external HDD that I formated in FAT32 using Mac OS X. I don't know how but it's unmountable in a Windows XP machine running SP3. The HDD size is 500Gb and it contains a single partition. Is there a way to make it mountable on a Windows machine without formatting it again?

I've checked the partition map scheme with Disk Utility and it's set to Apple Partition Map.

[edit]I would prefer a free tool but I don't mind learning about paid tools.[/edit]

Comment: Which version of Windows was this?  I know there are issues before XP SP1 with drives over a specific size, regardless of which partition type it is.

Comment: It's Windows XP SP3. I've edited the question to include that detail.

Comment: I haven't forgotten to accept one of the answers. I just had some really busy days. Hopefully I'll be able to test one last answer by the weekend and then I'll accept one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you create FAT32 partitions with a GUID partition scheme, XP cannot read the drive, requires MBR.

on a Mac click on the disk in disk utility and see what it shows under "Partition Map Scheme".

it is not possible to change from GUID to MBR without setting up the drive again, on a MAC with the correct option or on a Windows computer via disk management. either way, all data on the drive will be overwritten.

Comment: How can I change to MBR?

Comment: probably not without formatting again. but why using FAT32? use NTFS, much faster than FAT32 and not capped a 4GB file size. you can read/write NTFS disks on a Mac. http://www.lifehack.org/articles/lifehack/how-to-read-and-write-ntfs-windows-partition-on-mac-os-x.html

Comment: I used NTFS before but somehow it corrupted some of my mp3 files and I decided to go back to FAT32.

Comment: Molly - MacFUSE is still tagged experimental. I wouldn't recommend anyone use it for anything important.

Comment: +1: I ran across this today with one of my thumb drives.

Comment: @MarkM: i'm aware of that and anyone should decide for themselves. NTFS would be my personal preference. hence i did not include this in my answer but rather added a comment, raising the issue.

Answer (score 2):

When you format a drive under OSX, it uses the EFI partition table format (also called GUID), which isn't compatible with Windows (XP, Vista, or 7).

To resolve this, you need to format the drive as FAT32, and when you do so, click the small "Options" button in Disk Utility. You'll see this:

[image: Disk Utility Formatting Options]

You need to select "Master Boot Record" for the drive to work correctly under Windows. It's probably worth noting that there are more than likely a few ways mentioned in other answers to get the disk working without reformatting it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it doesn't answer my question. I now know how to prevent the issue whenever I format a new drive but I still don't have an answer on how to solve it without re-formatting.

Comment: I mentioned this towards the ending, however it may have been a little cryptic. You cannot fix this issue without reformatting the thumb drive unless you are willing to use one of the third party tools mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need a utility to mount it, such as [MacDisk](http://www.macdisk.com/mden.php3).

[image]

Comment: I'll have to wait until the weekend to test this answer.

Answer (score 0):

[iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php) from Coriolis can change the Partition Map Scheme from Apple Partition Map to MBR. At the time of this answer there were no free tools available.